# Line break in Linkedin API

Tags: php, api, share, linkedin-api, article

## Linkedin API Caption with Carriage Return

I'm using a carriage return on `Linkedin Caption` to share the post via `Linkedin Share article API`. But while sharing through API it returns an error like

> "Error parsing request body to JSON Illegal unquoted character ((CTRL-CHAR, code 10)): has to be escaped using a backslash to be included in string value\n at [Source: (com.linkedin.data.ByteString$ByteArrayVectorInputStream)"

Is there any way to resolve this issue and pass a carriage return in the caption. Please help.

I have tried to replace the carriage return using "\n" since it shows like escape using backslash but it's not working for me.

$msg = 'test1
        test2

```
    test3';
```

$msg = preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z ]/","\n",$msg);

I have tried the above but again I got the same error response from Linkedin API.

The expecting result to share a post with a caption like below,

"test1
 test2

test3"

But it won't get a post to the user account instead it gives an error like

> "Error parsing request body to JSON Illegal unquoted character ((CTRL-CHAR, code 10)): has to be escaped using a backslash to be included in string value\n at [Source: (com.linkedin.data.ByteString$ByteArrayVectorInputStream)"

Comment: Try putting an actual backslash-n in your string; when you write `"\n"`, php translates it to a newline and the API sees the same as before. (For example, write `"\\n"` in your code to insert real backslash.)

Comment: Show us your code where you are actually creating the JSON. Are you doing this manually? Then _stop that_, that is not a clever thing to do - create the appropriate _data structure_, and then use `json_encode` on it.

Comment: @alexis Thank you so much. I have tried your trick and it's work perfectly.

Comment: You are welcome. It's not a trick, it is regular PHP syntax for generating what the api asked for. I have written it out as an answer, please "accept" it to mark this question as resolved. (And then please do heed what @04FS wrote!)

Answer (score 0):

To insert a literal `\n` in a string, you need to escape the backslash; otherwise PHP understands the `\n` notation and will change it into an *actual* newline, which is what you are trying to avoid. So, write `"\\n"` instead of `"\n"` in your code snippet.

But the comment by @04FS is spot on: You should not be generating the json format yourself! Put your data in an array, without worrying about the escaping newlines and such, and use `json_encode` to serialize it.